# Ignore keywords in quotes in Vim Regex substitute

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace "as" in my SQL scripts with "AS", but I want to ignore those with in double quotes.

For example, in the following 4 cases:

1. `if(something = "something", "true", "false") as[1] test`
2. `if(something = "something", "something as[2] something", "is not") test`
3. `if(something = "something" and everything = "everything", "true", "false") as[3] test`
4. `if(something = "something", "something as[4] something", "is not") as[5] test`

I'm trying to write a regex substitute which would replace [1], [3], and [5], but not [2] and [4].

I tried negative lookbehind, but to no avail.

Any advice is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Will any instances of 'as' that are *not* enclosed in quotes ever be followed (on that line) by another quotation mark?  (In your examples, for `[1]`, `[3]` and `[5]` it is the case that there are no more quotations marks following the `as`.)  Anyway, if not, I think I have a way to do it.

Comment: @Turix, usually there will be no quotes after the keywords (in this example, "as"), but there might be some edge cases. Let me know about your solution. I would be happy to test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The canoncial way to do something like this is to do the search and replace based on the syntax group. There is the plugin [SrchRplcHiGrp.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=848) available for this, but you can also do this manually.

In your case place the cursor on the "as" that you want to replace and note syntax group to which it belongs:
`:echo synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.'),1), 'name')` This  displays the syntax name of the object under the cursor. For sql syntax, this should display **sqlKeyword**. Knowing this, you can replace using a `:s` command like this:

```
:%s/as/\=synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.'),1),'name')==#'sqlKeyword'?toupper(submatch(0)):submatch(0)/g
```

which basically says, if the syntax group of the matched "as" is sqlKeyword, make it uppercase else, replace it by itself.

Comment: Great tip, Christian! My original plan is to write a substitute function for each of the SQL keywords and put them all in a `sql.vim` script. Whenever I need to translate lower-case keywords into upper-case, I can then `source sql.vim` in command line. Does your solution using the plugin fit with the plan? In any case, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (most of) the instances of 'as' that you want to replace are never *followed* by quotation marks, you could use the following:

```
:1,$s/ as \([^"]\+\)$/ AS \1/
```

If a few of them are followed by quotes, but most aren't, you can add `c` to the end of the command to have it ask you to confirm each replacement, like:

```
:1,$s/ as \([^"]\+\)$/ AS \1/c
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version 1.40 of my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has a `:SubstituteNotInSearch` command. With that, you can uppercase the `as` only outside of double quotes:

```
:%SubstituteNotInSearch/"[^"]\+"/\<as\>/AS/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a solution, but this is the worse ever^^

enjoy

```
:'<,'>s/\"\zs\(\w\)/<\1/g | '<,'>s/\(\w\)\ze\"/\1>/g | '<,'>s/<.\{-}>/\=substitute(submatch(0),"as","<as>","g")/g | '<,'>s/as\[/ AS[/g | '<,'>s/[<>]//g
```